# Long, one column list in Excel, convert For SQL where in statement

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I have an arbitrarily long one column list in Excel.  I need to put this list in the where statement of SQL server.
There is a manual way of doing this: list starts at `A1 until A40`. Use `B1="'"&A1&"',"`.  This encloses each element of the list in `'',`.  Next `C1=B1 and C2=C1&B2..C40=C39&B40`
The final element in the list will have `,` manually removed.

[sample excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEvC2.png)

`Where recipID in ('1865','1733','1990')`

Everything is good if I do this once or twice a year.  But its becoming increasingly routine. I could record-a-macro and build off that.  However I'm more looking for a 2 in 1 macro that not only preps the data for SQL, but also copies to the clipboard - so that the only actions needed is to select the list, run macro, and paste into SQL.

Comment: Can't you just paste the "table" (i.e. the one-column list) from Excel into a table in SQL, and then use that in a `JOIN` statement?

Comment: yes I can! thanks for the idea!

Comment: Whoever decided to mark this as a duplicate clearly don't know how to read. VBA script and excel formulas are totally different things.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this **array formula**:

```
=LEFT(CONCAT("'"&A1:A40&"',"),LEN(CONCAT("'"&A1:A40&"',"))-1)
```

Enter the formula and press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to enter the array constant as an array formula. (You know it's working when you see the {} around the formula).

[Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7)

[image]

You could also add parentheses around it the same way you normally would.

```
="("&LEFT(CONCAT("'"&A1:A40&"',"),LEN(CONCAT("'"&A1:A40&"',"))-1)&")"
```

---

[CONCAT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CONCAT-function-9b1a9a3f-94ff-41af-9736-694cbd6b4ca2)

> Applies To: Excel 2016 Excel 2016 for Mac Excel Online Excel for iPad Excel for iPhone Excel for Android tablets Excel Mobile Excel for Android phones

---

An alternative to CONCAT is [StringConcat() by Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/stringconcatenation.aspx) which can produce the same result.

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate the feedback, the excel formula, the picture, and the guide link.  I forgot to mention I'm using 2013 version, but it seems the only difference is to use concatenate() over concat().  

On the topic of concatenate(), it doesn't seem concatenate(A1:A5) would work; but concatenate(A1,A2,A3,A4,A5) is needed.  Is this an issue related to 2013 and earlier?

Comment: Updated to include alternative version using [StringConcat() by Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/stringconcatenation.aspx)